Llama2-7b Long runtime to generate text from a prompt
I have loaded the Llama2-7b model from HuggingFace on to my computer to generate text based off of a simple prompt. The model loads pretty quickly (around 2 min) but then when I want to generate a really simple response from a simple prompt, such as "What is an LLM?" It takes the model over two hours to generate a response. I need this to be running faster but don't know what is wrong to make it run faster. Any suggestions?
Here is my Code:
class LlamaInference():
    """Text Generation class using Llama 70b param LLM. Generates a dataset."""
    def __init__(self, output_file_path):
        """ Initialize LlamaInference class and all variables
        Keyword arguments:
        output_file_path -- Location of output file after dataset generation
        """
        self.output_file_path = output_file_path
        self.pipeline = None
        self.output_list = []
        self.output_list_condensed = []

    def __set_up(self):
        """ Set up huggingface pipeline with specific model and revision
        """
        #model = "meta-llama/Llama-2-70b-chat-hf"
        #revision = "e6152b720bd3cd67afc66e36d06893a0e1f84b48"
        model = "meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf"
        revision = "08751db2aca9bf2f7f80d2e516117a53d7450235"


    
        self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model, padding_side="left")

        self.pipeline = transformers.pipeline(
            "text-generation",
            model=model,
            tokenizer=self.tokenizer,
            torch_dtype=torch.float16,
            device_map="auto",
            revision=revision,
            do_sample=True,
            return_full_text=False
        )
        self.pipeline.tokenizer.pad_token_id = self.tokenizer.eos_token_id


    def gen_text(self, prompt, **kwargs):
        """ Generates text based on a prompt

        Keyword arguments:
        prompt -- the question we are asking the llm
        **kwargs -- arguments to be passed to self.pipeline 
        """
        try:
            if self.pipeline is None:
                self.__set_up()
            if "batch_size" not in kwargs:
                kwargs["batch_size"] = 1
            
            if "max_new_tokens" not in kwargs:
                kwargs["max_new_tokens"] = 2048

            kwargs.update(
                {
                    "pad_token_id": self.pipeline.tokenizer.eos_token_id, 
                    "eos_token_id": self.pipeline.tokenizer.eos_token_id,
                }
            )
            display('started pipeline')
            token_outputs = self.tokenizer(prompt)
            display(token_outputs)
            outputs = self.pipeline(prompt, **kwargs)
            display('end pipeline')
            return outputs
        except Exception as error:
            display(f'__gen_text error: {error}')

inference = LlamaInference('test.json')
result = inference.gen_text("Hello", max_new_tokens=2048, batch_size=1, temperature=0.5)


LLMs are quite resource-intensive models. Are you using GPU?

Use a smaller model or get better hardware.
